# How to kill all processes that don't have specific parent process?

Tags: process, kill

A parent process should always be running with N children process.

I would like to run a script which will show/kill all children processes that don't have a parent process.

```
$ ps faux | grep process.pl
root 37140  0.3  0.1  61160 724   /process.pl [child]
root 22079 10.2  0.3 127332 64620 /process.pl [master]
root 22081  0.3  0.1  84752 26084   \_ /process.pl [child]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pkill` might work here:

```
$ pkill -P 1 process.pl
```

This kills all processes named `process.pl` whose parent is PID 1, which is what happens when a process's parent dies.

Comment: (assuming the _parent_ `process.pl` itself has not been reparented by `init` as well). Note that `pkill process.pl` would match any process whose name contains `process` followed by any character followed by `pl`. You'd need `pkill -x 'process\.pl'` or `pkill '^process\.pl$'` for processes whose name **is** `process.pl`.

Comment: Just make sure you do not kill process number 1! :-)

Comment: Thnx, I will experiment a bit to make sure that I don't kill anything important :D

Comment: @bbaja42: Any system with `pkill` on it should have `pgrep`, too, which has much the same command interface. So, if `pgrep -P 1 -x 'process\.pl'` lists all of the PIDs you want killed and nothing else, you can be reasonably sure that `pkill` isn't going to do something unexpected. The main danger then is that your test isn't run at the same time as the actual command, since the process table will be different at execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the pkill. I plan to compare output of pgrep and ps faux visually, and if all OK then run the pkill command.